# keyboard interruption handler. assembler

Tags: assembly, tasm

I need to write a program on assembler (TASM). It should write a message on console when any button was pressed.
It should be int 9h handler!
So how can I change standard keyboard handler for my own handler procedure:

```
keyboardhandler proc  
  mov ah,9  
  mov dx,offset myMsg
  int 21h
  iret
keyboardhandler endp
```

The simpler the better.
Thank you.

==============================================
So what I have now... There is a program

```
.model small
.386
.stack 100h

.data
old9 dd ?

.code

start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
jmp setup

prg proc
  mov ah,2
  mov dl,'X'
  iret
prg endp

setup:

  cli
  mov ax,0h
  mov es,ax
  mov bx,es:[9*4]
  mov word ptr old9,bx
  mov bx,es:[9*4+2]
  mov word ptr old9+2,bx
  mov word ptr es:[9*4],offset prg
  mov es:[9*4+2],cs
  sti

  int 09h ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; this one

  lds dx,dword ptr old9
  mov ax,2509h
  int 21h

  mov ax,4c00h
  int 21h
end start
```

It works great. But there is one issue. When I change the line int 09h for

```
mov ah,01h  
int 21h
```

it also print me the 'X' but after that program hangs (and ms-dos too).
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as simple as it may seem.  In order to output to the console, a system call is needed.  The system call needed (`write()`) is not allowed to be called from an interrupt handler.

Depending on which environment this runs on, different system calls are intended for this usage.  For example, under Linux, `kprintf()` is used to queue messages to the system log file which may eventually be displayed on the system console.

Since you are using TASM, probably you are running on MSDOS?  In that case, you could write directly to the screen text buffer by writing bytes at the correct position in memory.  However, this requires some management of *current cursor position* and whatnot.  You'll have to decide—or maybe someone already told you—what is an acceptable console display.

Answer (score 2):

> The simpler the better.

It will be much simpler to use MS-DOS's 21h interrupt, for example with [AH = 01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm).

int 9 seems to be a lower-level interrupt that works with keyboards scan codes.
This means you'll have to distinguish key presses and key releases.